# How do I resolve "Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0,PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The error occurs on this line:

```
ReportDocument rptd = new ReportDocument();
```

I have configured IIS to run 32-bit applications:

1. Open IIS
2. Go to current server – > Application Pools
3. Select the application pool your 32-bit application will run under
4. Click Advanced setting or Application Pool Default
5. Set Enable 32-bit Applications to True

If this option is not available to you, follow these next steps:

1. Go to %windir%\system32\inetsrv\
2. Execute the appcmd.exe tool:

But error persists.

Answer (score 1):

As the error describes:

you are missing the log4net.dll

you need to copy the described log4net.dll in the executing directory

Answer (score -1):

Comment this line in `web.config`

```
assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
```

and exclude `log4net.dll` from your References folder